# Finding the general solution to $2-4\cos (3x) = 0$

Tags: trigonometry, solution-verification

I don't get why I need to subtract $\pi/3$ to $2\pi$.
$$\begin{align}
2-4\cos (3x) &= 0 \\[4pt]
-4\cos (3x) &=-2 \\[4pt]
\cos(3x) &= 1/2 \\[4pt]
3x &= \frac{\pi}{3}
\end{align}$$
The general solution would be
$$
x= \frac{\pi}{9} + 2n\pi \tag1
$$
Is
$$x=\frac{5\pi}{9} + 2n\pi \tag2$$
would be an answer too?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to type the math in your question.

Comment: ohh sorry I'm  new, thank you!

Comment: The name of the constant is $\pi$ is pi, the greek letter, not pie the food.

Comment: I'm using my phone earlier, it keeps on replacing pi into pie

Comment: Also, don't ask two questions in the same post,  if you another question,  ask it separately.

Comment: Noted! I'll edit it now

Comment: So I think you got (correctly) as far as
$$
3x = \pm \frac{\pi}{3} + n2 \pi
$$
Now you only need to divide (all terms!) by 3 to get
$$
x = \pm \frac{\pi}{9}+ \frac{n2 \pi}{3}
$$
Also, I don't see what the title of the question has to do with the rest.

Comment: Do I need to subtract  
$$\frac {\pi}{3}$$  
to 2\pi? like looking for another angle. I mean I don't get why $$\frac{5\pi}{9}$$ is also a general solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general solution of
$$\cos x=\cos\alpha$$
is given by :

$$x=2n\pi \pm \alpha$$..(1)

Now , $2-4\cos{(3x)}$ can be re-written as
$$\cos{(3x)} = \frac{1}{2}=\cos\frac{\pi}{3}$$

Therefore , by equation (1)
Solutions are given by
$$3x=2n\pi \pm \frac{\pi}{3}$$

Or

$$x=\frac{2}{3}n\pi \pm \frac{\pi}{9}$$, where $n$ is an integer .

Comment: Can I ask about
$$ \frac {5\pi}{9} ± \frac{2n\pi}{9}$$

like it's in the 4th quadrant?